# PhpStorm, WebStorm проблема с автозавершением вызова цепочки методов класса JS

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

Есть js класс с набором методов, каждый из которых возвращает `this` для того чтобы можно было вызывать цепочку, например, `new MyClass().method1().method2()` и т.д.

Проблема заключается в автозавершении кода в PhpStorm. Так, первые 4 вызова при нажатии на точку появляются варианты методов из вызываемого класса, т.е. все как и должно быть. Вот пример.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот начиная с 5-й цепочки, автодополнение не предлагает вариантов методов из вызываемого класса. Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто знает в чем проблема и как ее исправить, прошу поделиться. Перепробовал все настройки автодополнения, прочитал всю документацию, ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Долго искал ответ, но безрезультатно, поэтому обратился в техподдержку PhpStorm.

Вот их ответ:

> Such behavior is expected and caused by an optimization. To have smart completion for longer method call chains, please add the following key to vmoptions file (**Help** | **Edit Custom VM Options...**): `-Didea.javascript.max.evaluation.depth=30`. Default value is 12.

Изменил в соответствии с рекомендациями и все заработало.

Оригинальный ответ по ссылке https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49852